# ¿Como selecciono el ID maximo de una tabla SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Utilizo el siguiente codigo para imprimir el ID mas alto de la tabla mensajes, pero no me funciona

```
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) 
 {
   $id = trim($row[0]);
 }
 
 echo $id;
```

Obtengo estos errores

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd5/581/15572581/public_html/index.php on line 382

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /storage/ssd5/581/15572581/public_html/index.php on line 383

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in /storage/ssd5/581/15572581/public_html/index.php on line 388

Comment: Falta codigo, por que los errores mencionan a mysqli_query, mysqli_result, y una ID sin definir.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el ID más alto de la tabla puedes hacer una consulta en la que obtengas los datos ordenados por ID en orden descendente y que te devuelva solamente un resultado.

```
SELECT * FROM mensajes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Si solamente quieres obtener el ID

```
SELECT id FROM mensajes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```